# tell cmake to be quiet

Tags: build, cmake

Is there a variable I can use in cmake to make it act like it was passed the -q option? It would be nice because I have a very modular build that gets messy with cmakes output. I am using it in a c++ project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no variable that I know of.  However, you can add the following hack to the start of your top-level CMakeLists.txt (before the `project` call) to control the output somewhat:

```
function(message)
  list(GET ARGV 0 MessageType)
  if(MessageType STREQUAL FATAL_ERROR OR
     MessageType STREQUAL SEND_ERROR OR
     MessageType STREQUAL WARNING OR
     MessageType STREQUAL AUTHOR_WARNING)
    list(REMOVE_AT ARGV 0)
    _message(${MessageType} "${ARGV}")
  endif()
endfunction()
```

This overrides CMake's built-in `message` command and suppresses all `STATUS` and untyped messages, leaving the more important types to output correctly.

The output of e.g. a `WARNING` message will change from

> ```
> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (message):
>   This is a dummy warning message.
> ```

to

> ```
> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:8 (_message):
>   This is a dummy warning message.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:14 (message)
> ```

Note that the actual line where the warning message was generated is listed in the call stack rather than being the first line of the output message.

Finally, this has no effect on the summary output which indicates success or failure of the configure attempt.

Comment: Cool! So You could do anytype of message you wanted to then huh?

Comment: Is there a way to stop that call stack stuff? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @alexhairyman Not really, but you need it to trace the actual source of the error/warning.  If you don't want to see even errors/warnings, you could always strip out everything inside the `function` body so that `message` becomes a no-op.  Or just leave the error types in the `if` and ignore warnings.

Answer (score 13):

As of cmake 3.1, setting [`CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html) is also very useful. For example, `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE LAZY)` will skip the `-- Up-to-date:` messages.

Comment: There's also set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE NEVER).

Answer (score 2):

```
set(CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL "WARNING")
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL.html

Comment: Didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the installation part of CMake, which tends to print one line per file (a la `-- Up-to-date: /some/destination/path` and `-- Installing: /some/destination/path`), you can do

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE LAZY)  # Don't tell us about up-to-date files.
```

which doesn't print for already present files (if you run install repeatedly, as you might during development), or even

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE NEVER)  # Install silently.
```

This [option has been present since CMake 3.1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html).