# Avoid the progress messages in CMake

Tags: cmake

Can I get rid of the CMake progress messages of the type:

> [  1%] make [5]: Entering directory ...
>   [  9%] Building CXX object ...

I've tried with setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`, `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE` to `OFF`, and others, but it never worked.
I've found `CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES=OFF` here: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=8726
but didn't work for me.
Also adding the function suggested here: [tell cmake to be quiet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509380/tell-cmake-to-be-quiet)
and didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3):

Set the global property [RULE_MESSAGES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/RULE_MESSAGES.html) to OFF:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_MESSAGES OFF)
```

Comment: Documentation you refers states: `If a CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES cache entry exists its value initializes the value of this property.`. But the asker says that setting this variable doesn't work for him. Probably he tried to set this variable in the CMake script, while documentation tells about **cache entry**. I think that describing correct usage of `CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES` variable could make your answer more useful.